# How can I realize a Mars program while Extended (pseudo) instruction or format not permitted is deactivated using the Operation NOT, ADDI and ADDIU?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

We have to extend our code. With these operations. [image: Operations]

Ziel= destination register

in line 14 im getting the error:  **line 14 column 2: Extended (pseudo) instruction or format not permitted.  See Settings.**

When i comment line 14. (#not $9, $9) i get this error
**line 27: Runtime exception at 0x00400064: arithmetic overflow
Go: execution terminated with errors.**

```
#code from previous question
1 .text 
2 addi $8, $0, 1
3 addi $9, $0, 11
4 addi $10, $0, 0x1000
5 addi $11, $0, -1
6 addi $12, $0, -0x8000
7 addi $13, $0, 0x8000
8 addi $14, $0, 0xffff0000
9 addi $15, $0, 0x7fffffff
10 addi $24, $0, 5322
11 addi $25, $0, 75

#code with operations
12 add  $2, $10, $9
13 sub  $3, $10, $9
14 not $9, $9 
15 add  $4, $9, $10
16 addi $4, $4, 1
17 sll  $5, $13, 5
18 sra  $6, $13, 5
19 sra  $7, $12, 5
20 srl  $16, $12, 5
21 srlv $17, $13, $9
22 div  $24, $25
23 mflo $18
24 div  $24, $25
25 mfhi $19
26 addiu $20, $15, 1
27 addi  $21, $15, 1
28 clo   $22, $11
29 clo   $23, $14
```

Comment: Use `addu` to avoid overflow. It's unclear what you want to do, so it may not be correct but it will avoid the overflow. To simulate `not` you can subtract from -1.

Comment: The instruction `not` is a "pseudo-instruction". This means that this is not really an instruction but an abbreviation for either one or two instructions. `not $x,$y` is an abbreviation for `nor $x,$y,$0`.

Comment: i can not use addu. i get the error messag Extended (pseudo) instruction or format not permitted.  See Settings. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWzCa.png this is what i have to do.

Comment: You must replace `addi  $21, $15, 1` by `addiu  $21, $15, 1`

Comment: Line 27 **will** overflow. Your assignment makes no sense. If you ignore overflow, it's the same as the previous line 26.

Answer (score 0):

Never use `addi` or `add`, unless you specifically want to trap on signed overflow.

Use `addu` or `addiu` to get signed wraparound (because MIPS is a 2's complement machine).

2's complement signed addition is the same binary operation as unsigned integer addition, so the `addiu` is the right instruction for both the "signed" and "unsigned" adds in your image.

---

Obviously if one of the operands is an immediate, you have to use `addiu`.

`addu $t1, $t2, 1` would only be supported as a pseudo-instruction, maybe by creating the constant `1` in a register for an `addu` instruction, or by assembling it as `addiu`.

---

MIPS doesn't have a `not` instruction.  You implement bitwise inverse in terms of the `nor` instruction with the zero register:  `nor $dst, $src, $0`.